# Can't catch 400 Bad Request with javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, wildfly-11

I have a REST service method that uses the `POST` http method and accepts `application/json`. The JSON is bound to a JAXB bean:

```
@POST
public void test(final HierResult obj) throws Exception {
    printHierResult(obj);
}

@XmlRootElement
public static class HierResult {
    public String dummy;
}
```

I noticed that when somebody sends me a syntactically valid JSON containing unknown field, say `{ "aaa": "bbb" }` then no error is logged, but the web server returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: WildFly/11

Unrecognized field &quot;aaa&quot; (class HierResult), not marked as ignorable
```

**So the question is: how do I log this error?**

I registered an `ExceptionMapper` for `java.lang.Exception`, but it can only catch `JsonParseException` or the exceptions thrown by my java method, not the error above.

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionLogger implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExceptionLogger.class);
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final Exception exception1) {
        LOGGER.error("", exception1);
        return Response
            .serverError()
            .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity(String.valueOf(exception1.toString()))
            .build();
    }
}

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }
    private void addRestResourceClasses(final Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(MyExceptionLogger.class);
    }        
}
```

Comment: There's no BadRequestException thrown, so there's nothing to catch. What happens is that Jackson has ExceptionMappers for JsonParseException and JsonMappingException and they return a response of 400. You can would have to make your own mappers for the same exceptions to override this behavior.

Comment: I need exactly the same. Has anybody some code to share to solve this?

Comment: @phe see the answer

Answer (score 2):

As @PaulSamsotha commented, had to register a mapper that has same or more pricise exception class.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <version>2.10.2</version>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

_

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException;

public class TestMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UnrecognizedPropertyException> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final UnrecognizedPropertyException exception1) {
        LOGGER.error("server side error", exception1);
        return Response
            .serverError()
            .status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity(String.valueOf(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))
            .build();
    }
}
```